# How to add "component" and "to" props to custom component based on Button?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to make custom component based on material-ui Button component. The point is to add some style to it and always use "contained" variant with added disableElevation prop. Everything is great until I need to use my RoundButton with component={Link} and adding router link to "to" property. This works fine with basic Button component but not with my one. I just don't get it how to set up suitable properties for it.

```
const RoundButtonBase = styled(Button)({
    '&.MuiButton-root': {
        borderRadius: '200px',
        fontSize: '16px',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        paddingLeft: '20px',
        paddingRight: '20px',
        backgroundColor: '#395994',

        '&.Mui-disabled': {
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'
        }
    }
});

type RoundButtonProps = Omit<ButtonProps, 'variant' | 'disableElevation'>;

export function RoundButton(props: RoundButtonProps) {
    return (
        <RoundButtonBase
            {...props}
            variant="contained"
            disableElevation
        />
    )
}
```

This works only with out-of-the-box Button component:

```
<Button
    component={Link}
    to={`/obligations/place-new-order/${this.props.obligation.docId}/`}
>Place new order</Button>
```